# If B1>B2 then B1 else B2 condition

Tags: google-earth-engine, conditional

I'm trying to implement OC3 equation to the Landsat 8 dataset.
In order to do so I need implement this equation :
[image]

I need to choose the highest reflectance between B1&B2 at each timestep.
I tried this  :

```
print(B1)
var B2 = collection.select(['SR_B2'])
var greater = ee.Filter.greaterThan(B1, B2)
var max = ee.Algorithms.If(greater, B1, B2)
print(max)
```

But they told that ee.Algorithms.If is not a function. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need the `ee.Algorithms.If` for this. You want to apply a `max(a,b)` operation. You can simply use `ee.Image.max()` for your `a` image with `b` as the argument (see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-max), i.e. your code should be `a.max(b)`,

If we apply this to an arbitrary Landsat image, where `a` is `SR_B1`, and `b` is `SR_B2`, it may look something like this:

```js
// Max of B1 or B2 (per-pixel operation)
function maxb1b2(img){
  //https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-addbands
  return img.addBands(
  // https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-max
    img.select("SR_B1").max( 
      img.select("SR_B2")
    )
    .rename("maxB1B2")
    )
}
```

where I decided to return the same image, but with an extra band called `maxB1B2` added to it. This is optional, depending on what you want to do. Here's a small demonstration, with the added code for applying the Landsat scaling factors:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e10a31cede6a1d998df0aacf9f2f2a0c

Comment: Thanks for your help, the objectif is to implement the OC3 equation in order to estimate chlorophyll-a concentration. The equation is 10^(a0 + a1*x + a2 * ^x^2 + a3 * x^3 + a4*x^4) a1->a4 are constant. Do you have an idea of how to implement it ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_math#expressions

Comment: Just for information, what is the function applyScaleFactors(image) use for ?

Comment: Take a look at the bands information here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands  The data is stored in integer numbers (1 to 65455). To convert them to actual reflectances, you need to apply the scaling factor and offset provided for each band.